# Prevent users to come up in search engines

Tags: feature-request, users, search-engine, robots

I have discovered that Users come up in search results which is annoying for me as my username is the same as the name that I produce apps under.

This means that my Stack Exchange profiles come up in search results online, possibly even before my own site.

Can Stack Exchange add user profiles to the `robots.txt` please so search engines won't index it.

Comment: change your username then

Comment: I rely on that feature to show up on-line...

Comment: I have now changed my username.

Comment: yes, so we see - interesting name

Comment: You expected SE to be hidden behind walls and unsearchable by search engines??

Answer (score 11):

This is quite a useful feature to me. I like that people looking for me find my useful contributions on SE. And you can't actually blame SE for being good in SEO.

If you don't want others to find your SE contributions when searching for your name, just change your username to something else.

Comment: The most important piece of advice is doing so at registration, since the Internet remembers all.

Comment: Not anymore @DeerHunter . I have [the right to be forgotten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_be_forgotten)...

Comment: @rene - yeah. As if three-letter folks care about our rights...